# How to implement Window Function in Apache Flink?

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, streaming, apache-flink

everyone,
I have a kafka topic source, I group it by a 1 minute window. 
What I want to do in that window is to create new columns with Window Function as in SQL, for example I want to use

- SUM(amount) OVER(PARTITION BY
- COUNT(user) OVER(PARTITION BY
- ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY

**Can I use DataStream functions for these operations?**    ***or***

**How can I operate my kafka data to convert it to DataTable and use sqlQuery?**

Destination is another kafka topic.

```scala
    val stream = senv
      .addSource(new FlinkKafkaConsumer[String]("flink", new SimpleStringSchema(), properties))
```

I've tried to do this

```
val tableA = tableEnv.fromDataStream(stream, 'user, 'product, 'amount)
```

but I get the following error back

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.flink.table.api.ValidationException: Too many fields referenced from an atomic type.
```

test data

```
1,"beer",3
1,"beer",1
2,"beer",3
3,"diaper",4
4,"diaper",1
5,"diaper",5
6,"rubber",2
```

Query example

```sql
    SELECT
     user, product, amount,
     COUNT(user) OVER(PARTITION BY product) AS count_product
   FROM table;
```

expected performance

```
1,"beer",3,3
1,"beer",1,3
2,"beer",3,3
3,"diaper",4,3
4,"diaper",1,3
5,"diaper",5,3
6,"rubber",2,1
```

Comment: please post one data sample from Kafka.

Comment: Also post the SQL query you want to achieve.

Comment: Your stream is of String type and you are trying to access fields from it. This explains your exception.  `Too many fields referenced from an atomic type`

Comment: hi, the query is: SELECT
  user, product, amount,
  COUNT(user) OVER(PARTITION BY product) AS count_product
   FROM table;

Comment: How do I apply the scheme so I can convert it to a table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to parse the string into fields and then rename them afterwards.

```scala
val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
val tEnv = StreamTableEnvironment.create(env)

val stream = env.fromElements("1,beer,3",
 "1,beer,1","2,beer,3","3,diaper,4","4,diaper,1","5,diaper,5","6,rubber,2");

val parsed = stream.map(x=> {
 val arr = x.split(",")
 (arr(0).toInt, arr(1), arr(2).toInt)
})

val tableA = tEnv.fromDataStream(parsed, $"_1" as "user", $"_2" as "product", $"_3" as "amount")

// example query
val result = tEnv.sqlQuery(s"SELECT user, product, amount from $tableA")

val rs = result.toAppendStream[(Int, String, Int)]

rs.print()
```

I'm not sure how can we implement the desired window function in Flink SQL.  Alternatively, it can be implemented in simple Flink as follows:

```scala
parsed.keyBy(x => x._2) // key by product id.
      .window(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.milliseconds(2)))
      .process(new ProcessWindowFunction[
        (Int, String, Int), (Int, String, Int, Int), String, TimeWindow
      ]() {
        override def process(key: String, context: Context,
                             elements: Iterable[(Int, String, Int)],
                             out: Collector[(Int, String, Int, Int)]): Unit = {
          val lst = elements.toList
          lst.foreach(x => out.collect((x._1, x._2, x._3, lst.size)))
        }
      })
      .print()
```

Comment: thanks!  I've used this syntax   fromDataStream(parsed, 'user, 'product, 'amount)

Comment: `flink_streaming_scala_2.11` only,  the lib which contains:  `StreamExecutionEnvironment` class.

Comment: "override def process( )" makes me mistaken error, tells me Method 'process' overrides nothing

Comment: the input or output types might be mismatched.

Comment: sorry for asking so many questions. I put the error marked by IntelliJ in this screenshot https://i.ibb.co/jbN5bWm/dddd.jpg

Comment: What is tge data type of your stream before process?

Comment: https://i.ibb.co/f849BhV/flink2.png  is the "val parsed = stream.map", of the original answer. the real data will come from kafka, but for the proof of concept I don't get it

Comment: What happens when you remove the `process` method?

Comment: I did manage to execute. Could you help me with the next question on the same thread? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61922101/apache-flink-processwindowfunction-keyby-multiple-values

Comment: What was the issue?

Comment: apparently none, I deleted the override process function and recreated it with the intelliJ assistant is the same, but it stopped marking error, and I'm using TumblingProcessingTimeWindows because I don't have event times, but it's great. now I have the doubt of how to group/aggregate two fields in the same process

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214308/discussion-between-logan-and-chuckskull).